# Does "sudo apt-get" installs 32bit or 64bit by default?

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit

Ubuntu 13.04 64bit
Does "sudo apt-get install" installs 32bit or 64bit by default?
e.g. If I try Does "sudo apt-get install postgresql" which version will it install?

Comment: It will install the version that corresponds to your architecture, unless you add `:i386`ad the end of the package name on a 64 bit system.

Comment: What about "sudo aptitude install" ? Don't have much experience with that, does it let you pick what package you want?

Comment: The same for `aptitude`, `aptitude install <package-name>:i386` installs the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get install` installs the versions that corresponds to your architecture.